# For positive functions $f,g$, if $g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$, and $g'(x) \geq 0$, $g''(x) \leq 0$, is $f'(x) \leq 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, functions

Suppose we have $x \geq 0$, and functions $f$ and $g$ such that for all $x$,
$$f(x), g(x) \geq 0$$
$$g(x) = x\cdot f(x)$$
$$g'(x) \geq 0$$
$$g''(x) \leq 0$$

I have been trying to prove that $f'(x) \leq 0$ or find a counterexample otherwise, but have been unable to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write $f(x)=\frac{g(x)}{x}$ and note that $f'(x)\leq 0$ if and only if $h(x):=xg'(x)-g(x)\leq 0.$

Now observe that $h(0)=0.$ Therefore, it suffices to show that $h$ is non-increasing, that is, $h'(x)\leq 0.$ But we know that $h'(x)=xg''(x)\leq 0$ if $x\geq 0.$

Comment: If $f(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, and $g(x) = 1$, then $h(x) = 0-1 < 0$, so the claim doesn't hold?

Comment: Your function $f$ is not defined on $[0, \infty)$ and it will not extend continuously to $0$. But anyway, it does not matter. It doesn't violate the claim. 

Since $f(x)=g(x)/x$ holds on $(0, \infty),$ the first line of the proof works on $(0, \infty).$ The only trouble one may possibly have is that $h(0)=0$ may not be available (to get this I used that $f$ is continuous at $0$). But the proof as you can see will work even if $h(0)\leq 0$ or even if $\lim_{x\to 0}h(x)\leq 0.$